# Spring Batch multithreading vs partitioning

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement where I want to use the Spring batch framework for below scenario.

I have a table which is partitioned on trade date column.
I want to process the records for this table by using reader, processor and writer of Spring batch framework.
What I want to do is create separate threads for reading, writing and processing based on trade date. Suppose there are 4 trade dates then I want to create 4 separate threads each one for separate trade date. In each thread the reader will read the records from the table for that trade date, enrich the records in processor and then publish/write in writer.

I am new to Spring batch, so I need help in designing the right approach for this by using Spring batch multithreading or partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use local partitioning like follows:

```
<batch:job id="MyBatch" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <batch:step id="masterStep">
        <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="splitPartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="4" task-executor="taskExecutor"  />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Then create the splitPartitioner using the org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner interface. Then in partition method, split the source data as you like and every ExecutionContext you create, will be executed by it's own thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **local partitioning** or **master-slave** approach to fix your problem. Write your master and slave steps as follows in Spring configuration.

```
<batch:job id="tradeProcessor">
    <batch:step id="master">
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="tradePartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="4" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </batch:step>       
</batch:job>
<batch:step id="slave">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="dataReader" writer="dataWriter"
                          processor="dataProcessor" commit-interval="10">
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

For more details, you can refer the simple example discussed [here](http://javatopper.blogspot.com/2014/12/scaling-up-batch-job.html).